# multiply all columns by 100 except first column ( index column or the epoch datetime )

Tags: python, pandas

i have read a csv file into a pandas dataframe

```
 df= pd.read_csv(filename, sep=",", header = None, usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Here is the format of dataframe

my initial Dataframe:

```
           0       1        2        3        4     5
 0  1451606820  1.0862  1.08630  1.08578  1.08578  25
 1  1451608800  1.0862  1.08630  1.08578  1.08610  10
 2  1451608860  1.0862  1.08620  1.08578  1.08578  16
 3  1451610180  1.0862  1.08630  1.08578  1.08578  27
 4  1451610480  1.0858  1.08590  1.08560  1.08578  21
 5  1451610540  1.0857  1.08578  1.08570  1.08578   2
 6  1451610600  1.0857  1.08578  1.08570  1.08578   2
 7  1451610720  1.0857  1.08578  1.08570  1.08578   2
 8  1451610780  1.0857  1.08578  1.08570  1.08578   2

 Column '0' = Datetime in Epoch time 
 Columns 1,2,3,4,5 are values
```

i want to only multiply columns 1,2,3,4,5 by 100  without changing column 0 or multiplying column 0 by 100

i tried

```
  df.multiply(100)
```

but it multiplies every column by 100 including column 0 .

Also on my Column 1  the decimal points keeps getting truncated to 4 instead 5 like other columns. i am not sure what is causing that even though in the csv file i have

```
   1451606820 , 1.08622 , 1.08630 , 1.08578 , 1.08578 , 25
   1451608800 , 1.08626 , 1.08630 , 1.08578 , 1.08610 , 10
   1451608860 , 1.08623 , 1.08620 , 1.08578 , 1.08578 , 16
   1451610180 , 1.08627 , 1.08630 , 1.08578 , 1.08578 , 27
   1451610480 , 1.08588 , 1.08590 , 1.08560 , 1.08578 , 21
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set index from first column by parameter `index_col` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and then multiple:

```
df= pd.read_csv(filename, sep=",", header = None, usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], index_col=0)
```

and then

```
df = df.mul(100)
```

Or:

```
df = df * 100
```

---

Another solution is select by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and multiple:

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:] * 100

df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].mul(100)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:] * 100
print (df)
   A    B    C    D    E    F
0  1  400  700  100  500  700
1  2  500  800  300  300  400
2  3  600  900  500  600  300
```